# Setup RabbitMQ consumer in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application where I would like to consume RabbitMQ messages.

I have successfully set up the publishers and consumers in command line applications, but I'm not sure how to set it up properly in a web application.

I was thinking of initializing it in `Startup.cs`, but of course it dies once startup is complete.

How to initialize the consumer in a the right way from a web app?

Comment: Are you sure ASP.NET is the right place to host the RabbitMQ consumer ? Can you have command line app consuming RabbitMQ messages, and upon receiving them post to ASP.NET  ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it would be the most convenient because we don't currently have a regime to deploy and run other types of apps. I suppose a Windows Service would do the trick, but if there is a safe and sound way to do it from our web app that would be great

Comment: It could also be worth mentioning that the web app in question already does related background jobs with Hangfire, so it feels like a logical place to place it

Comment: Hangfire!!! Check out [Integrate HangFire With ASP.NET Core](http://dotnetthoughts.net/integrate-hangfire-with-aspnet-core/). I think that can be a good starting point since you have both - HangFire & ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hangfire is not about long lived objects. Huge overhead.

Comment: I see many problems with using a request/response host (a web server) for hosting a long-lived eventing consumer. Keeping a stable number of consumers across recycles, IIS shutting down the process etc adds extra complexity and web servers are simply not designed for this use case. I see that hangfire also supports hosting in Windows Services, so that way you might be able to get the benefit of hangfire and an appropriate host.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the Singleton pattern for a consumer/listener to preserve it while the application is running. Use the `IApplicationLifetime` interface to start/stop the consumer on the application start/stop.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<RabbitListener>();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRabbitListener();
    }
}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtentions
{
    //the simplest way to store a single long-living object, just for example.
    private static RabbitListener _listener { get; set; }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRabbitListener(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _listener = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RabbitListener>();

        var lifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();

        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);

        //press Ctrl+C to reproduce if your app runs in Kestrel as a console app
        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);

        return app;
    }

    private static void OnStarted()
    {
        _listener.Register();
    }

    private static void OnStopping()
    {
        _listener.Deregister();    
    }
}
```

- You should take care of where your app is hosted. For example, IIS can recycle and stop your code from running.
- This pattern can be extended to a pool of listeners.

Comment: what is RabbitListener  here ?

Comment: @Prageeth it is just the code to take messages from the queue. Your own implementation  would depend on the system requirements and the queue definition. You can find a lot of examples in the web, and one of those is https://github.com/plwestaxiom/RabbitMQ/blob/master/RabbitMQ_Tutorials/RabbitShared/Receiver.cs#L28

Comment: consumer.Received += (model, ea) => this called only once when application startup and not listening.I dont know if I miss anything Llya.

Comment: I miss this line  Console.ReadLine(); if I put this it works charm.

Comment: When use `Console.ReadLine()` you don't have any problem but when removing `Conosle.ReadLine()` just one time execute consumer, but i use [IHostService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) but these make me run tow console app at a same time, one for **ASP.NET Core MVC 2** project and one for **RabbitMQ Client**

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Can you provide the whole example using the RabbitListener ?

Comment: @JustDontKnow the general pattern is close to the Paldi's example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52494986/5112433. You operate the same set of RabbitMQ API's and add a real-world stuff to it (serialization, error handling) if needed.

Comment: it's work only if go to web page. If i leave 1-2 minuts and rabit channel off. How i can fix it?

Comment: or if start iis and don't open page, rabbit not start

Comment: Alternatively you can still use DI but inject the whole MQClient and then use it; while manage the connectivity out of the consumers but actually inside the Rabbit MQClient class - so this approach is fairly straight forward.
See the example implementation:
https://programmer.ink/think/the-right-way-to-use-rabbitmq-in-net-core.html

Answer (score 17):

This is My Listener:

```
public class RabbitListener
{
    ConnectionFactory factory { get; set; }
    IConnection connection { get; set; }
    IModel channel { get; set; }

    public void Register()
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            int m = 0;
        };
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
    }

    public void Deregister()
    {
        this.connection.Close();
    }

    public RabbitListener()
    {
        this.factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        this.connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        this.channel = connection.CreateModel();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is [Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

You can create a **HostedService** and call a method to register `RabbitMq` listener.

```
public interface IConsumerService
{
    Task ReadMessgaes();
}

public class ConsumerService : IConsumerService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IModel _model;
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    public ConsumerService(IRabbitMqService rabbitMqService)
    {
        _connection = rabbitMqService.CreateChannel();
        _model = _connection.CreateModel();
        _model.QueueDeclare(_queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false);
        _model.ExchangeDeclare("your.exchange.name", ExchangeType.Fanout, durable: true, autoDelete: false);
        _model.QueueBind(_queueName, "your.exchange.name", string.Empty);
    }
    const string _queueName = "your.queue.name";
    public async Task ReadMessgaes()
    {
        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(_model);
        consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
            _model.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        };
        _model.BasicConsume(_queueName, false, consumer);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_model.IsOpen)
            _model.Close();
        if (_connection.IsOpen)
            _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**RabbitMqService**:

```
public interface IRabbitMqService
{
    IConnection CreateChannel();
}

public class RabbitMqService : IRabbitMqService
{
    private readonly RabbitMqConfiguration _configuration;
    public RabbitMqService(IOptions<RabbitMqConfiguration> options)
    {
        _configuration = options.Value;
    }
    public IConnection CreateChannel()
    {
        ConnectionFactory connection = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            UserName = _configuration.Username,
            Password = _configuration.Password,
            HostName = _configuration.HostName
        };
        connection.DispatchConsumersAsync = true;
        var channel = connection.CreateConnection();
        return channel;
    }
}
```

And finally create a **HostedService** and call **ReadMessages** method to register:

```
public class ConsumerHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConsumerService _consumerService;

    public ConsumerHostedService(IConsumerService consumerService)
    {
        _consumerService = consumerService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _consumerService.ReadMessgaes();
    }
}
```

Register services:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IRabbitMqService, RabbitMqService>();
services.AddSingleton<IConsumerService, ConsumerService>();
services.AddHostedService<ConsumerHostedService>();
```

In this case when application stopped, your consumer automatically will stop.

Additional information:

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "RabbitMqConfiguration": {
    "HostName": "localhost",
    "Username": "guest",
    "Password": "guest"
  }
}
```

**RabbitMqConfiguration**

```
public class RabbitMqConfiguration
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The code is not working. it is showing DI error.

Comment: @sina_Islam Share your error message

Comment: nore even the consumer consume the message.

Comment: @sina_Islam I don't know how you implement `rabbitmq` .  For more information you can check [this link](https://dotnetdocs.ir/Post/43/implementing-rabbitmq-in-.net-core)

Comment: thanks brother, it is working. Actually, I am implementing it at nopCommerce as a plugin to consume order place event and missed some configuration that is why it was not working properly. Your code is perfect and working as expected.

Comment: awesome! for anyone following this code example, don't forget to link the configuration to the configuration class in **Program.cs**: `builder.Services.Configure<RabbitMqConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMqConfiguration"));`

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways I found is to use a `BackgroundService`

```
   public class TempConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _channel;

    public TempConsumer()
    {
        _factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "localhost",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "password",
            VirtualHost = "/",
        };
        _connection = _factory.CreateConnection() ;
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "queue",
                                durable: false,
                                exclusive: false,
                                autoDelete: false,
                                arguments: null);
    }
  
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

        consumer.Shutdown += OnConsumerShutdown;
        consumer.Registered += OnConsumerRegistered;
        consumer.Unregistered += OnConsumerUnregistered;
        consumer.ConsumerCancelled += OnConsumerConsumerCancelled;


        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved");
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
            _channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        };


        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: "queue",
                             autoAck: false,
                             consumer: consumer);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnConsumerConsumerCancelled(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerUnregistered(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerRegistered(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e) { }
    private void RabbitMQ_ConnectionShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e) { }
```

Then, Register the consumer as a hosted service
`services.AddHostedService<EmailConsumer>();`