# RabbitMQ consumer in ASP.NET Core application whith out the web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

Summary i do how it resolved in [Setup RabbitMQ consumer in ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609345/setup-rabbitmq-consumer-in-asp-net-core-application/43610530#comment98659771_43610530)
but my Rabbit consumer online if i do web request, if i start IIS and don't start browser request, Rabbit consumer is not started.
Have any one know why? 
Can a web application do the work of a web application and a Windows service or  is it a bad idea.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton<RabbitListener>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRabbitListener();
        ...
    }

}
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtentions
{
    //the simplest way to store a single long-living object, just for example.
    private static RabbitListener _listener { get; set; }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRabbitListener(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _listener = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RabbitListener>();


        var lifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();

        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);

        //press Ctrl+C to reproduce if your app runs in Kestrel as a console app
        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);

        return app;
    }

    private static void OnStarted()
    {
        foreach (var o in LogOptions.Options)
            _listener.NewRouteAdd(o.QueueString);
        _listener.Register();
    }

    private static void OnStopping()
    {
        _listener.Deregister();
    }
}
```

Comment: Services are only started once they are actually used. So on starting up the application on IIS you need to explicitly make a call to a method/route that uses the service. At least that's how we solved this issue before.

Comment: Maby it can be call in "static main",before create service or any one net mvc object can do it?

Comment: so now we have background worker ihostedservice :)

Answer (score 0):

The OnStart() runs once, when your application receives the first HTTP request 
I think the best option for you is to create a Windows Service for consuming messages or any application that keeps alive connection

I suggest for you these links:
https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-19-part4-rabbitmq-13-common-errors.html
https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-12-29-part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html