# .NET Core - gracefully handle failure on startup and retry on next request

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, rabbitmq, application-pool

I have a .NET Core web service that is running on IIS. As part of start up, the service will connect to RabbitMQ. However, if for some reason the connection fails then the service will crash during start up.

This happens a number of times until the IIS Rapid-fail protection policy kicks in and shuts down the application pool. This then requires a manual restart to get things running again.

Is it possible to handle the exception in the Main() method and, whilst not starting up the app, prevent IIS from seeing this as a failure, thus avoiding the rapid fail protection? Ideally the service would then start up again on the next incoming request.

Update:

I figured it out myself. Basically you can stop the application and it will start up again on the next incoming request:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    try
    {
        webHost.Run();
    }
    catch (StartMessageBusException)
    {
        // If we cannot connect to RabbitMQ on startup then we want to
        // gracefully shut down the app. This way IIS will try to start the app again on the next request
        await webHost.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you connecting as a subscriber or as a consumer?

Comment: @GlennSills I’m connecting as a consumer

Comment: "However, if for some reason the connection fails then the service will crash during start up" most likely indicates an unhandled exception. You should learn how to handle them well, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @LexLi I’m unsure how to handle the exception in a way that prevents the issue with IIS outlined above :)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. We had to do two steps:

1. Shut down all your background jobs by calling `await webHost.StopAsync();`.
   Just to be sure that all your background jobs (including the WebHost listening for HTTP requests) end properly.
2. Notify IIS that the app execution ended by calling `Environment.Exit(-1);`.
   IIS 10 does not start the process again when you do not send the exit code.

The full example:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    try
    {
        webHost.Run();
    }
    catch (StartMessageBusException)
    {
        await webHost.StopAsync();
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Environment.Exit(-1) causes application pool to stop, which is undesirable if you want your next request to start the app again. Did you face the similar issue?

Comment: @Andy, Personally not. Take a look at Rapid Fail Protection that comes into play in such a scenario.  It is described for example [here](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/4190/What-is-Rapid-Failed-Protection-in-IIS-and-what-is-the-usage-of-it.html)

Comment: Ok it seems to work when Rapid Fail Protection is disabled. Do you see any risk or downside to disabling Rapid Fail Protection for app pools?

Comment: @Andy, I am not an expert in the IIS configuration. If you host the app as a standalone, then it shouldn't be a problem. But if the app is part of any cluster (like AKS), where the status code 503 on the service detects downtime, then it may lead to an issue in monitoring services. In such a case, the service will be detected as healthy even though it should indicate an unhealthy state.

Answer (score 0):

This answer here has a good description of how to set up RabbitMQ inside an asp.net core webapi app in general -  [Setup RabbitMQ consumer in ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609345/setup-rabbitmq-consumer-in-asp-net-core-application)

I'd suggest you do exception handling and retries within the singleton.